# Pushing other elements down while Content Area grows

Tags: html, css

I don't understand, but I did it before and now it is not working. I created a basic HTML and CSS files, and I have a content area that needs to grow when a client decides to insert more content in the content area, but it is not working. The content area is overlapping other elements that are below. Could someone please help, and explain why?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Boulineau's Website</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidelinks">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sidenav_03.png" alt="IGA" width="180" height="165" border="0" title="IGA Grocery Store" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_05.png" alt="Ace" width="180" height="115" border="0" title="Ace Hardware" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_06.png" alt="Eugene" width="180" height="100" border="0" title="Eugene Platt's Seafood" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_07.png" alt="Barnacle" width="180" height="90" border="0" title="Barnacle Beach Shoppe" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_08.png" alt="Hut" width="180" height="100" border="0" title="The Dairy Hut" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_09.png" alt="Ocean" width="180" height="90" border="0" title="Ocean Treasures Resort Wear" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_10.png" alt="Shell" width="180" height="85" border="0" title="Shell & Car Wash" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_11.png" alt="Laundromat" width="180" height="85" border="0" title="Laundromat" /></a>
        </div><!-- end of sidelinks -->
    </div><!-- end of sidebar -->

    <div id="weeklyspecials">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/weeklyspecials_03.png" alt="Weekly Specials" width="269" height="58" border="0" title="Click for Weekly Specials" /></a>
    </div><!-- end of weeklyspecials -->

    <div id="mainimage">
        <img src="images/mainimage_03.png" alt="Main Image" width="648" height="319" border="0"  />
    </div><!-- end of mainimage -->

    <div id="navigationbar">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" alt="Home Page" width="45" height="14" border="0" title="Home Page" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/aboutus.png" alt="About Us" width="65" height="14" border="0" title="About Us" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/cherrygrovebeach.png" alt="Cherry Grove Beach" width="120" height="14" border="0" title="Cherry Grove Beach" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/specialevents.png" alt="Special Events" width="92" height="14" border="0" title="Special Events" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/tidecharts.png" alt="Tide Charts" width="77" height="14" border="0" title="Tide Charts" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/employment.png" alt="Employment" width="82" height="14" border="0" title="Employment" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/printablecoupon.png" alt="Printable Coupons" width="98" height="14" border="0" title="Printable Coupons" /></a>
    </div><!-- end of navigation -->

    <div id="content">
        <P>
            <img src="images/lobster.png" alt="" width="329" height="229" border="0" title="" />
        Content Area needs to grow...anything below gets push down. 
        </P>
    </div><!-- end of content -->

// These div down delow must be push down by the content area when it grows.
    <div id="video">
        <img src="images/video_03.png" alt="Video" border="0" width="263" height="193" title="Video" />
    <div><!-- end of video -->

    <div id="weeklyadbox">
        <img src="images/weeklyad.jpg" alt="Weekly Ad" border="0" width="178" height="147" title="Weekly Ad" />
    </div><!-- end of weeklyadbox -->

</div><!-- end of container -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
} 

body {
text-align: center;
background-image: url("../images/waterbg.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: center, top;

}

div#container {
background-image: url("../images/contentbg_02.jpg");
width: 900px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
height: auto;
}

div#sidebar {
float: left;
position: relative;
left: -40px;
top: 14px;
background-image: url("../images/sidebar_03.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 314px;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 1161px;
z-index: 5;
}

div#sidelinks {
position: absolute;
left: 72px;
top: 275px;
cursor: pointer;
}

div#weeklyspecials {
float: right;
margin-top: 47px;
margin-right: 17px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

div#mainimage {
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 90;
right: 13px;
z-index: 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

div#navigationbar {
background-image: url("../images/nav_03.png");
width: 620px;
height: 44px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: right;
position: relative;
margin-top: -780px;
margin-right: 25px;
}

div#navigationbar img {
margin-top: 15px;
}

div#content {
background-image: url("../images/welcome2.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 657px;
/*height: 368px;*/
z-index: 100;
float: right;
margin-top: -732px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
}

div#content p {
float: left;
margin-top: 140px;
margin-left: 10px;
text-align: left;
line-height: 30px;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: georgia;
border: 1px black solid;
}

div#content p img {
float: right;
}


div#video {
margin-top: -258px;
margin-left: -90px;
padding-top: 10px;
top: 900px;

}

div#weeklyadbox {
float: right;
margin-top: -198px;
margin-right: 80px;
background-image: url("../images/weeklyadbox_04_03.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 243px;
height: 284px;
padding-top: 120px;
position: relative;
}
```

In case you are wondering, I use borders a lot for references. Anyway, I tried creating an empty div called spacer after the closing div tag with an `id="content"` and used `clear: both`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried `clear:both` in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hUGBz/1/) and it dropped everything below the content div. Also, the closing div for `video` isn't closed properly. You're missing the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid even having issues like these I suggest using a CSS framework. Foundation provides a 12 column flexible grid that I really like. You can find it at: http://foundation.zurb.com

If you were to rewrite you HTML using this framework it would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>Welcome to Boulineau's Website</title>

    <!-- Included CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->


    <!-- IE Fix for HTML5 Tags -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

    <!-- container -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="four columns"><!-- left nav -->
                <a href="#"><img src="images/sidenav_03.png" alt="IGA" width="180" height="165" border="0" title="IGA Grocery Store" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_05.png" alt="Ace" width="180" height="115" border="0" title="Ace Hardware" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_06.png" alt="Eugene" width="180" height="100" border="0" title="Eugene Platt's Seafood" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_07.png" alt="Barnacle" width="180" height="90" border="0" title="Barnacle Beach Shoppe" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_08.png" alt="Hut" width="180" height="100" border="0" title="The Dairy Hut" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_09.png" alt="Ocean" width="180" height="90" border="0" title="Ocean Treasures Resort Wear" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_10.png" alt="Shell" width="180" height="85" border="0" title="Shell & Car Wash" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/sidelinks_11.png" alt="Laundromat" width="180" height="85" border="0" title="Laundromat" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="eight columns"> <!-- right area -->
                <div>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/weeklyspecials_03.png" alt="Weekly Specials" width="269" height="58" border="0" title="Click for Weekly Specials" /></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/mainimage_03.png" alt="Main Image" width="648" height="319" border="0"  />
                </div>
                <div class="row"> <!-- nav -->
                    <div class="one columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" alt="Home Page" width="45" height="14" border="0" title="Home Page" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/aboutus.png" alt="About Us" width="65" height="14" border="0" title="About Us" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/cherrygrovebeach.png" alt="Cherry Grove Beach" width="120" height="14" border="0" title="Cherry Grove Beach" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/specialevents.png" alt="Special Events" width="92" height="14" border="0" title="Special Events" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/tidecharts.png" alt="Tide Charts" width="77" height="14" border="0" title="Tide Charts" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/employment.png" alt="Employment" width="82" height="14" border="0" title="Employment" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one columns">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/printablecoupon.png" alt="Printable Coupons" width="98" height="14" border="0" title="Printable Coupons" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row"> <!-- content -->
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                        <P>
                        <img src="images/lobster.png" alt="" width="329" height="229" border="0" title="" />
                        Content Area needs to grow...anything below gets push down. 
                        </P>
                    <div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/video_03.png" alt="Video" border="0" width="263" height="193" title="Video" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/weeklyad.jpg" alt="Weekly Ad" border="0" width="178" height="147" title="Weekly Ad" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->




    <!-- Included JS Files -->
    <script src="javascripts/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Aside from reducing common CSS issues - that come up a lot. This framework provides a simple model an consistency as well as several other handy things like nice built in buttons, tabs, and mobile support and detection.